# R - summary function does not return IQR info on column

Tags: r

I'm trying to determine the mean value for a column for a data frame. Originally, the column had `?` values which I converted into `NA` values. However, when I try to find the mean, I get this result:

```
> mean(brc_wisc$F6, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default(brc_wisc$F6, na.rm = TRUE) :
  argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA
```

And when I try to find the summary info:

```
summary(brc_wisc$F6)
?    1   10    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9 NA's 
0  402  132   30   28   19   30    4    8   21    9   16
```

Yet I can get the summary statistics for any other column:

```
mean(brc_wisc$F1)
[1] 4.41774

summary(brc_wisc$F1)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
  1.000   2.000   4.000   4.418   6.000  10.000
```

What would I have to do to be able to get the mean and summary values for the modified column?

Comment: did you import this data from a csv or similar? you can try `read.csv(..., na.strings = c('NA', '?'))` which may fix this issue from the start (also add more strings which should be interpreted as `NA` if you need)

Comment: I did import from csv, that parameter did enable me to find the summary and mean, thank you!